# Adjacent cells (Top and Left) drawing over custom painted border when selected

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Pictures showing the above issue:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHmmL.jpg

Here's the code I am using to draw the border around select cells:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex > 0 && e.RowIndex > -1)
    {
        if (e.Value != null && (!e.Value.Equals("0")) && (!e.Value.Equals("-")))
        {
                double d = Convert.ToDouble(e.Value);

                    if (e.ColumnIndex == 2)
                    {
                        int limit = Convert.ToInt16(numericUpDown1.Value);

                        if (d > limit)
                        {
                                int pWidth = 1;
                                Pen p = new Pen(Color.Red, pWidth);
                                e.PaintBackground(e.CellBounds, true);
                                e.PaintContent(e.CellBounds);
                                int x = e.CellBounds.Left – pWidth;
                                int y = e.CellBounds.Top – pWidth;
                                int w = e.CellBounds.Width;
                                int h = e.CellBounds.Height;
                                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(p, x,y,w,h);
                                e.Handled = true;
                        }
                    }
          }
    }
}
```

Is there any way to have them not disappear? It doesn't happen to the bottom and right borders. I've tried several things including:

- Disabling borders and drawing my own for all cells (same issue)
- Adjusting draw rectangle to be inside cell (don't like the look)
- Handling CellEnter/CellLeave/CellClick to .Invalidate the row and column in an attempt to get the custom bordered cell to re-paint over the top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried out TaWs answer (was able to comment at the time) and it didn't resolve the issue but got me thinking. I needed to invalidate those cells any time any other cells were drawn so I added event handlers to the following:

- CellMouseDown
- CellMouseUp
- SelectionChanged
- Form_Activated

And instead of invalidating adjacent cells as it didn't seem to be working, I invalidated the displayed column rectangle of that column as it's the only one currently which has the custom bordered cells.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that two paint events are conflicting:

- Your CellPaint draws the nice red borders..
- ..and **after** that, the system draws the selected cell destroying your red borders in the neighbouring cell.

Actually it is even worse, depending on how you move the selection, especially when you move it up or down, because now not only the selection is painted but also the previous selection restored, destroying the red borders in the cell above or below as well!

I'm not sure why this happens asymmetrically; maybe it is the old DrawRectanlge bug, which tends to draw sizes off by one. (Which is why you can't draw a Rectangle with a size of 1; you need to fill it!) Or maybe there is something odd about the order of events..

Be that as it may, you will solve the problem simply be forcing a fresh painting of the affected cells using `InvalidateCell`:

```
private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewCell cell = dataGridView1.CurrentCell;
    if (cell.ColumnIndex < dataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1)
    {
        dataGridView1.InvalidateCell(cell.ColumnIndex + 1, cell.RowIndex);
        if (cell.RowIndex > 0) 
            dataGridView1.InvalidateCell(cell.ColumnIndex + 1, cell.RowIndex - 1);
        if (cell.RowIndex < DGV.ColumnCount -1)
            dataGridView1.InvalidateCell(cell.ColumnIndex + 1, cell.RowIndex + 1);
    }
}
```

You may want to optimze it for your owner-drawn columns..